# Does XCode have something similar to properties files in Visual Studio

Tags: ios, xcode

**Background**

I'm porting a small Windows application to iOS using XCode 6.2 as both the IDE and build platform.  I have a workspace created, which I'm using to compile and build all the projects.  I currently build every project except the actual iOS app as a dynamic library, and then embed it in the final app package on deployment.

**The Problem**

I'm currently hard coding relative paths in the projects.  Stuff like `../../shared-headers` - I really don't like doing this as I have to figure out this path per project, and I'd prefer to use something like props files in Visual Studio, which would let me do something like `$(SHARED_HEADERS)` in projects.

This makes the projects easier to maintain, and any dependency extremely obvious.  It also makes it much easier to move projects when the need arises.  What is the preferred method to do this in XCode?

**EDIT:**  I'd like to stick with a Visual Studio-ish include structure.  While [Copying headers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/iOSStaticLibraries/Articles/creating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012554-CH2-SW1) is a good way to manage some of the complexity, I do not prefer this method because it will add time to the build, and developers from Windows will not be expecting this.

Comment: When you setup frameworks and static library projects correctly, you shouldn't have issues with public headers from these projects. Did you read the relevant Xcode documentation how to use static libraries and frameworks in iOS projects? [See here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/iOSStaticLibraries/Introduction.html)

Comment: See also: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/EditingBasicSettings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010155-CH19-SW1

Answer (score 0):

I too was looking for the same thing, and i've just found it! using an xcconfig file!

Create a .xcconfig file either from xcode's file menu or just a simple text file, and add your entires like so:

PATH_TO_SOME_SDK = Volumes/DEV/Project

SOME_DEFINITION = 7

once you add that file to the project, you can add it (or different ones) to each configuration in the project's info panel under "Configuration".
the definitions along with their values will then appear in the project's build settings under "User-Defined", and will change dynamically as the value in the file changes.
you can then use the values in any other build setting like any other environment variable or macro:
$(PATH_TO_SOME_SDK)

for more info:
https://nshipster.com/xcconfig

https://medium.com/better-programming/working-with-xcode-configuration-files-398cfbe02b64

https://help.apple.com/xcode/#/dev745c5c974

better late than never...
:-)